# Score Brainfuck as 0.5 bytes per char (because it only uses 8 characters)?

Tags: discussion, code-golf, scoring

I think that Brainfuck and many other esoteric languages almost never win [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), because they take many characters to express things. So, overall, **Brainfuck programs are longer in bytes, because they use only eight different characters. I think that it isn't fair to give each character one byte in a language which uses just over 3 per cent of the ASCII charset.**

I'm suggesting this simple amendment to the scoring rules of [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) which will give some esoteric languages more of a chance.

If you have a character set of only 16 characters, each character is 4 bits. Hence, you can store 2 characters in one byte.

So, in languages which have 16 or fewer useful characters (e.g. Brainfuck, any others?), **every character should count as 0.5 bytes** (unless the program contains ASCII characters which are not in our set of 16, in which case normal scoring applies).

Similarly, for languages such as Whitespace, which uses 3 different characters (correct me if I'm wrong), you could count every char as 0.25 bytes, unless the program contains other chars.

I'm a bit reluctant about giving HQ9+ the 0.25 byte privilege, but ultimately there's no reason why not - we all know it's a joke, it won't somehow become more clever if we allow it to be scored like this, and if we didn't let HQ9+ have 0.25 bytes per char it would be a confusing exception to the rules.

### TL;DR (too long, didn't read)

I think that in languages that use 16 or fewer different characters, and ignore all others (e.g. Brainfuck), every character should count as half a byte for [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf). This will give more of a fair chance (?) to many esoteric languages, and allow them to compete with more respectable things.

Comment: You can still have many functions even if using 16 characters (eg. there are 65536 different four character combinations), so people may make 16-character languages which are completely acceptable, just to get this bonus on their code.

Comment: @kitcar2000 Good point, but creating your own language for a question is "no longer funny": http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/standard-loopholes-which-are-no-longer-funny.

If someone makes a special language which uses 16 characters, and it gets popular, then we could accept it just as we accept HQ9+ or GolfScript. But then it wouldn't be cheating, because you aren't creating it for a specific question.

Comment: speaking of HQ9+ - does this means that these rules now provide us a 0.25-byte quine _and_ a 0.25-byte hello-world?

Comment: @JanDvorak Unfortunately yes... but as I explained, HQ9+ won't suddenly get more upvotes. It's still a complete joke. Even without these rules it can still beat any other language.

Answer (score 6):

This doesn't need to be in the site's rules because it already exists in the real world.

For example, let me define my own language called "BitF*ck," directly mapping BF commands to bits:

```
+ 000
- 001
> 010
< 011
. 100
, 101
[ 110
] 111
```

Now each BF character is .375 bytes, and look, we didn't need to change any of the site's rules! Similarly, we could map HQ9+ to `00 01 10 11` and get .25 bytes per character.

The advantages of this are:

1. We have an objective way of determining how many bytes a character should be (just use bits instead of characters!).
2. It's already used in the real world
3. No special cases are needed - just map any language to a set of bits and you're good for every challenge from that point on
4. No arguments about what a "character set" is

You could always provide a BF program alongside the binary translation, to make it easier to understand.

Comment: Good idea, but ultimately creating your own language is still frowned upon, and just counting BF chars as 0.5 is simpler

Comment: This is basically a Huffman encoding of bitfuck and would be relatively easy to implement. I wonder why there aren't any esolangs that take advantage of compression techniques like this.

Comment: Sorry, but I [independently did this](https://esolangs.org/wiki/CompressedFuck)

Comment: @professorfish When has that ever been frowned upon? Never.

Comment: @LegionMammal978 "Sorry"? This post was posted in 2014 and your link says you created it in 2015.